# OpenSSL decrypt error - Padding versus Raw

Tags: encryption, cryptography

I am receiving an encrypted file and it's key from a partner. The Key has itself been encrypted using our Digital Certificate Public Key.

When I attempt to decrypt the key using the following and our private key, I get a padding error as shown below:

```
C:\openssl rsautl -decrypt -in xxxx_Key -inkey xxxxprivatekey.pem -hexdump -out aeskey.txt
Loading 'screen' into random state - done
RSA operation error
5612:error:0407109F:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:pkcs decoding er
ror:.\crypto\rsa\rsa_pk1.c:273:
5612:error:04065072:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PRIVATE_DECRYPT:padding check failed:.\
crypto\rsa\rsa_eay.c:602:
```

If I add the `-Raw` switch to the decrypt,  it appears to work but the resulting hexdump is WAY larger than I'm expecting.  Can anyone offer advice as to what may be going on here? Thanks!

Comment: The question is of course how it was encrypted: which padding and encoding were used?

Comment: In addition to the comment of Artjom: have you tried `-oaep` and `-ssl` options as well?

Comment: Hi Maarten, I have tried those. No help.  Artjom, that of course IS the question. The problem is I'm dealing with the IRS and can't get any response out of them on this.  All they tell me is how to decrypt  what they're sending and it's not working so I'm left to puzzle it out!

Comment: Dear Firebladeboy, Do you have any update. We are facing the same problem with the IRS right now

Answer (score 10):

My guess is that you are decrypting with the wrong private key or your ciphertext is corrupted.

In RSA, padding is used to extend the length of the message being encrypted to be the same size as the modulus (so 1024 bit RSA pads messages to 1024 bits). PKCS1 type 2 is (I believe) another name for PKCS#1 v1.5 which adds the padding `0x00 || 0x02 || (random bytes) || 0x00` to the start of the message. When decrypting the first check that is done is that the start of the message is `0x00 0x02`. Then all bytes up to and including the second `0x00` are stripped off, yielding the original message. If the start is not `0x00 0x02` or there is no second `0x00` byte then there is a padding error.

If you ignore the padding check you most likely will get a message the same size as the RSA modulus since no padding is stripped off. Considering most RSA moduli are at least 1024 bit this will be much larger than an AES key.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation.  Neither end of my -hexdump -raw key seems to fit  that description though.  It looks like this: 17fcbd502b........f8aa4. In total, it's 512 characters!

Comment: A 4kbit RSA key (modulus) would have a length of 512 bytes. It's quite possible that the IRS is using 4kbit keys.